# PHP on XAMPP not Interpreting Variable Containing Relative Path Correctly

Tags: php, xampp

I am trying to do some work on a small e-commerce site, that I am now in charge of. The site is running on an Apache server (not sure what version, the HTTP responses will only tell me it's "Apache") on Linux, with PHP 5.3.24. The site runs fine on the server, hosted by Network Solutions and really only uses PHP to dynamically generate pages, with no DB interaction, as at present, we're using the PayPal shopping cart in addition to them handling the final transaction.

I decided to do some developing on my home XAMPP Apache/MySQL/PHP installation - (maybe not the best choice), specifically:

XAMPP for Windows 1.7.3

Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

All this runs on (wait for it....) Windows XP SP3.

When I ported the site over to my server, the index page loads fine - it's all straight HTML but when I try to go to the next level into the site, some resources are not loading.

Here's an example of a .php file that gets built dynamically, using includes:

```
<?php

$pageID = "category1" ;
$mainPane_filename = "category1.inc";
$rootDir = "../";
$categoryID=$cID = "item_pv";
$sb_filename = "php/itemlist.php";

include($rootDir . "php/template.php"); 

?>
```

In this instance, the assignment of the variable '$rootDir' works without incident, and my XAMPP installation has no problem with the syntax:

'include($rootDir . "php/template.php");'

There is a problem however, with the links in the template.php file.

While the file has a .php extension, and does contain some isolated php scripting, the majority of it is HTML. Seems like the PHP interpreter doesn't like stuff like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=$rootDir?>ns_stl.css">
```

There are numerous links like this pointing to mostly graphics files. These links don't live inside of script tags and are straight HTML except for the syntax:

```
<?=$rootDir?>
```

These are interpreted fine on the live server but my XAMPP installation gives me the error:

[Sun Apr 24 20:50:12 2016] [error] [client 192.168.29.249] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: Cannot map GET /niche/menu/%3C?=$rootDir?%3Eimages/navi6.jpg HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://192.168.29.249/niche/menu/category1.php

I notice that the error msg has rendered the <> characters as URL encoded, and I've tried changing some of the links to contain: '%3C?=$rootDir?%3E', but no joy.

Anyone have any clue as to what might be going on?

To anyone who has endured this far, I send a heartfelt "Thank You!"

Answer (score 0):

I would start by removing the php short tags, Change

```
    <?=$rootDir?>
```

to

```
    <?php echo $rootDir; ?>
```

Here is an article that addresses some of the problems associated with short tags. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php

basically any where in your code that you see

```
 <?= should be changed to  <?php
```

This will most definitely help on XAMPP. It probably wouldnt hurt to change them on the live server either.